# Sorting mixes numbers and characters in grid view

Tags: c#, sorting, radgrid

I have **Order code** which has characters and numbers in my **telerik RadGrid** like :**`"DO-2016-1"`**, the sort operation sort them as string without take in consideration the **numeric** included in the **order code**. How can I solve the problem

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a few order code examples and then how you want them to be sorted, so we can a broader picture? The order code you 've given in your text, could very well just be a date-string and doesn'T tell us anything.

Comment: @Serv image is added

Answer (score 1):

One way is by doing it like this:

1. Split your `order code` by `string.Split('-')`
2. Put them into a new class called `OrderCode` which have three members (1. DO, 2. 2016, 3. 1) - let say, the name is `firstNo`, `secondNo`, and `thirdNo`
3. Put each of them into `List<OrderCode>`
4. Use LINQ `OrderBy` instead of `Sort`, order your `List<OrderCode>` the way you want it
5. Recreate the `string` for each `OrderCode` if neccessary:

   ```
   string newStr = oc.FirstNo.ToString() + "-" + oc.SecondNo.ToString() + "-" oc.ThirdNo.ToString();
   ```

Note: you can apply the concepts above the way it fits with your code